# How can Crossfilter be used with unflattened multidimensional datasets?

Tags: multidimensional-array, nested, filtering, relational, crossfilter

Suppose I have a dataset with a one to many relationship. For example, every teacher has many (an array of) students, so the data might be nested like:

```
[
    {
        teacher: {
                    'name': 'Ann'
                 },
        students: [ ... ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Can I use Crossfilter with the data formatted like above? Or must the data be flattened, as in many of the examples?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to operate on the nested entities as the basis for grouping, filtering and aggregating then you should flatten the data.

The fundamental unit that Crossfilter operates on is the array element, which are most easily thought about in terms of flat rows.  In many of Crossfilter's functions, your code is fed each array element so that you can drive the various operations (group, filter, etc...).

Technically you can get away with navigating each element's contents on the fly and essentially return flattened values dynamically.  But each of these functions essentially needs to return a single value so you'll be constantly fighting to figure out what this value should be in cases where you have multiple nested entities under a single top-level element.

So, I wouldn't say it is impossible to work with nested data but you will be limited in terms of what you can express naturally and the complexity will increase dramatically as you try to work around these limitations.

I think flattening is definitely the way to go. In my experience Crossfilter is much easier to understand if you think about the data elements as rows in a relational database.